# how to do a background-image transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a day and night background with transition.
This is what i have so far: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4csF3/).

This is how i change day and night, but i can't fade them into each other

CSS:

```
.day
{
    background-image: linear-gradient(orange,lightyellow);
}
.night
{
    background-image: linear-gradient(#111111,darkblue);
}
```

JQUERY:

```
function dayAndNight(){
    if($('#achtergrond').attr('class')== "night")
            $('#achtergrond').toggleClass('night day');
    else if($('#achtergrond').attr('class')== "day")
            $('#achtergrond').toggleClass('day night');
}

setInterval(function(){dayAndNight();},2000);
```

how can i fade day into night and night into day?

Comment: Two divs, one fades out, one fades in.

Comment: _how can i fade day into night and night into day?_  Just give it twelve hours or so and it'll happen all on its own...

Comment: ... you can't explain that.

Comment: Some like this http://jsfiddle.net/htdN9/17/ ... or to keep overlapping and fade you may need to have two divs

Comment: @Danko i wanted to overlap so i tried it with two divs

Comment: @Jeremy thanks, the two divs worked brilliantly

Comment: @breght: I was about to post this as an answer but I think a link here will work: http://jsbin.com/UBeJEMU/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yep @breght check this one line in jquery then http://jsfiddle.net/htdN9/29/

Comment: Nice. Never used fadeToggle.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. If you want to make a day and night transition. The setInterval() Function of 
javascript is a really bad idea. 
Its better if you use the getHours() function.

```
var date = new Date(); 
var h = date.getHours(); 
alert(h);
```

You will get the current hours. 
Now you can just have an if statement like

```
if(h>6){
   //Its Evening
}
```

This is a tried and tested code for the day and night transition you want.

```
var date = new Date(); 
var h = date.getHours();
if(h<6){
    $('#achtergrond').attr('class','day');
    $('#achtergrond').fadeIn();
}else{
    $('#achtergrond').attr('class','night');    
    $('#achtergrond').fadeIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Background-image transition can be achieved with some animation effect with following steps -

1. Change element Opacity by (-0.1)
2. Add small delay of 10 milliseconds and do step 1, till opacity reaches 0.
3. Set new background-image for element.